# Enum Java Not saved as Strings with Enumerated Annotation

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I am not able to create Enumerations to be saved as Strings in MySQL DB.
I have a MySQL table with a field:

status varchar(50)

**Enum**

```
public enum Status {OPEN, CLOSED, CANCELLED, DONE}
```

**Entity**

```
@Column(name="status", nullable=false)
private Status status;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status getStatus() {return status;}
```

When I launch my application, I have the following error while fetching data:
**SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() 'OPEN'**

Also I cannot create an Entity, I have a SQLGrammarError. It's trying to save the object with status=OPEN instead of status='OPEN'.

I followed the documentation [JavaDoc Persistence Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html)
And tried this [tutorial Jpa and Enums](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html)

By adding the @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) on the attribute status. The fetching error is not there, but I still have the same error to create the entity.

**Error Log**

```
[DEBUG] com.vallois.valcrm.web.rest.BusinessResource - REST request to save         Business : Business{id=null, name='test', description='okokok',     createUpdateInfo=CreateUpdateInfo{createdUsername='user', updatedUsername='null',  createdDate=Thu May 21 16:04:54 CEST 2015, updatedDate=null}, status=CLOSED,  lock=PUBLIC}
Hibernate: insert into BUSINESS (created_date, created_name, updated_date, u pdated_name, description, lock, name, status, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,    ?, ?, ?)
[WARN] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
[ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lock, name, status, user_id) values ('2015-05-21 16:04:54', 'user', null, null, ' at line 1
```

Comment: Show your configuration, particularly including your table schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move `@Enumerated` to the field

```
@Column(name="status", nullable=false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;
```

**EDIT**

The exception you are getting is unrelated to enums. `lock` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, you'll have to change it's name to something else.

Comment: It's not working, still have the error to create the entity. The enumeration is trying to be created as status=OPEN instead status='OPEN'. I have a MySQL error.

Comment: Can you post the exception and the code that is causing it?

Comment: The exception you are getting is unrelated to enums. `lock` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, you'll have to change it's name to something else.

Answer (score 2):

JPA allows annotations either on fields or on properties, where the place of @Id specifies which of the two is considered.

So in this case I guess you will have to move `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` to the field.